# Method showSelection() is undefined

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rap

I am working with a RWT web-application and I need to select a piece of text and scroll to it. I use:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
...
Text multiLineText;
...
multiLineText.setFocus();
multiLineText.setSelection(point);
```

But in this case, if the selected piece of text is not in the text control (lower or higher), I need to scroll to it.

I try to add a line of code:

```
multiLineText.showSelection();
```

But my compiler says **The method showSelection() is undefined for the type Text**. Documentation says, this method is defined:

http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FText.html

Comment: What about the version you use? Is it the same you check the documentation for?

Comment: I think you can get something here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/eclipse.html

Comment: I use the version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2). The doc is for Luna (4.4)

Comment: Most likely this is something that is not implemented in RWT.

Comment: So, is there a way to scroll to a selected text in RWT?